# Can someone help me with a swap transaction?

Tags: transactions, swap, liquiditypool

sorry to bother but Im struggling since a couple of days. Im new on this but I want to learn.
I have a script that listen new pools and try to make a swap. I have SOL on my wallet but keep saying that I do not have funds. Is there a way to determinate the minimun balance required from the pool?

ERROR:

> SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction
> simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program
> error: 0x28

And also I have a function to determinate initialrate but is always giving me zero and also that make the transacction fail.

```
async function getInitialRate(connection: Connection, poolKeys: LiquidityPoolKeys): Promise<number> {
    try {
        
        if (poolKeys.baseDecimals === 0 || poolKeys.quoteDecimals === 0) {
            throw new Error("Información del pool inválida: decimales no pueden ser cero");
        }

        const rawAmountIn = 10000000; // 0.01 SOL en lamport
        const swapInDirection = true; // 
        const { executionPrice } = await calcAmountOut(
            connection, poolKeys, rawAmountIn, swapInDirection
        );

        if (!executionPrice) {
            throw new Error("No se pudo calcular el precio de ejecución");
        }

        const rate = parseFloat(executionPrice.toFixed(10));
        console.log('Exchange Rate:', rate);
        return rate;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error calculando la tasa de cambio:', error);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

can someone guide me?

thank you

Comment: What pool are you using? Which program are you listening to? Do you know how to call the program with the right instructions? It might be that you don’t wrap sol into wSOL first. Take a look at [Jupiter’s guide](https://station.jup.ag/guides/general/wrapped-sol)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.